# What does `<|` means in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, unmarshalling

I've a code using [Marshal](https://github.com/utahiosmac/Marshal).

```
class MediaModel: Unmarshaling {
    var id: Int64
    var videoUrl: String?
    var text: String?

    required init(object: MarshaledObject) throws {
        id =        try object <| "id"
        videoUrl =  try? object <| "videos.original_url"
        text =      try? object <| "text"
    }
}
```

**what does `<|` stands for here ?**

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look at this [Marshal source code](https://github.com/utahiosmac/Marshal/blob/master/Sources/Operators.swift) you can see what it does stand for. Custom operator written. 
This custom operator used for get value from the MarshaledObject dictionary by key.

```
// MARK: - <| Operator

infix operator <|

public func <| <A: ValueType>(dictionary: MarshaledObject, key: String) throws -> A {
    return try dictionary.value(for: key)
}
```